# How to ban user on pinging someone?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot on, when pinging the owner, auto bans the author that pinged the player. The issue is, it bans the player for saying anything, how would I make it that it'd only ban if they pinged the owner?

Here's the code.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '<@329005206526361610>'
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Wary's Defender Bot is up");
});
function getUserFromMention(mention) {
    if (!mention) return;

        if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
            mention = mention.slice(1);
        }
        if (mention.startsWith('<@329005206526361610') && mention.endsWith('>')) return {
          //  mention = mention.slice(2, -1),    
        return: client.users.cache.get(mention)

    }
}

client.on('message', _message => {
    // if(!_message.content.users.has('@warycoolio')) return;
    const user = getUserFromMention(_message.content);
    if(user) return;
    console.log('found target')
    var  member = _message.author
    var rMember = _message.guild.member(_message.author)

    // ban7, 'lol.' 
  rMember.ban({ days: 7, reason: 'They deserved it'}); {
        // Successmessage
        console.log('target dead.')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a quick check to see if the mentions include a mention to the owner of the server, and then ban the user.

```js
client.on("message", _message => {
    if (_message.mentions.users.first().id === "owner id") {
        message.author.ban()
    }
})
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: You name the message parameter `_message` , yet you use `message` (?)

Comment: @Elitezen yeah my bad i just didn't realize it because i'm used to the variable being named message it should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking `_message.mentions.users` with `.has()` and passing in the guild owner's id.

1. Use `.has()` instead of checking message content, this will automatically check the `Message#mentions` collection.
2. Dynamically get the guild owner's id using `Guild#ownerID`.

```
client.on('message', _message => {
   if (_message.mentions.users.has(_message.guild.ownerID)) {
      _message.author.ban({ days: 7, reason: 'They deserved it'});
   }
});
```